# How to kill jobs from a script that didn't clean them up

Tags: bash, job-control, jobs

I have a script that started a job but didn't clean it up. The job is running in a loop in the background and I don't know which process it is and it's not listed in `jobs`. It's printing spam in my terminal and I don't know how to get rid of it without rebooting the whole machine.

How do I locate and kill this rogue job?

Example annoying script:

```
function _sleepy_time() {
   while true; do
      time sleep 1s
   done
}

_sleepy_time &
```

Comment: Use e.g. `ps` to check what processes are running and kill the offending process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ps a` to show the current processes.

Look up the PID according to your COMMAND, e.g.:

```
$ ps a
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  974 pts/4    S      0:00 bash annoying_script.sh
```

and kill it with:

```
$ kill 974
```

Comment: I was trying to figure it out using `top -u`. This is much more useful.